# Analytics php api get json response (UA)

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, universal-analytics

I run this query via the analytics api, to get my results:

```
$ids = "ga:xxxxxx";
$start_date = "2015-01-01";
$end_date = "2015-10-08";
$metrics = "ga:pageviews";
$dimensions = "ga:pagePath";
$optParams = array('dimensions' => $dimensions, 'output' => 'json');
$data = $analytics->data_ga->get($ids,$start_date,$end_date,$metrics,$optParams); 
$items = $data->getRows();
```

Currently I get an array as response, but I want a json string.
What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. The PHP client library returns an object [Google_Service_Analytics_GaData](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Service/Analytics.php#L6520), You can either convert that object into a [JSON object](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/fb00b4206d09b8caf22308cb90619cf0222d7629/src/Google/Model.php#L130) or you could construct your API request with out the client library to get at the direct API response.